# Magento2 Event after Default Billing address change, How to send email if Billing address change?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, email, billing-address, address

I want to send an email to admin if the default billing address selection is changed or the values are changed by the customer.

How can I achieve this?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no Magento event created for this. you will need to override controller in your custom module to achieve this functionality.